# How to start django session on demand?

Tags: django

when using django middleware, for every new visitor, a new session record or session file is created. this is fine except for websites where a large traffic part do not need session (exemple : a blog that is seen by many but written by only one).Is it possible to have the session middleware activated only for some urls so many I/Os will be saved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not true. Sessions are lazily created, so only if data is put in the session a new record is created. Have a look here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L27

Comment: Yes you are right I finally found that a middleware I use intialize the session with an empty list for each request. I will fix that...

Comment: not true, if you check session (request.session.get('lang', 'en')), session objects creates as well.